# Owl Carousel 2 add change items number on Click

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel-2

Is there any way I can change Owl Carousel items limit on click. As I'm working on grid and list view without reloading and I want to change Owl Carousel items on click on list view button. Like I have 2 Items recently showing on grid giew once I clicked on list view it will show only 1 item.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled view-holder">
    <li class="view-box grid-view active">
        <a href="javascript:;">Grid View</a>
    </li>
    <li class="view-box list-view">
        <a href="javascript:;">List View</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="owl-carousel feature-carousel">
    <div class="item"> 1 </div>
    <div class="item"> 2 </div>
    <div class="item"> 3 </div>
    <div class="item"> 4 </div>
</div>

var itemList = 2;

var $owlFeatureSlider = $(".feature-carousel");

$owlFeatureSlider.owlCarousel({
    rtl: rtlVal
    , loop: false
    , margin: 30
    , nav: false
    , items: itemList
});

$(".list-view").click(function () {

    $owlFeatureSlider.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

    if(itemList == 2){
       var itemList = 1;
    }

});
```

Comment: please better to show code what you have tried?

Comment: @Kumar please check I have add my code above let me know if this help you to understand.

Comment: can you show markup too

Comment: Done. See on page reload owl carousel shows 2 items which is fine but when  I click on .list-view class I want 1 item will show in owl carousel.